# WSO2 ESB - Calling a VFS Transport from a Scheduled Task

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to run a VFS Transport at a specific time of the day, so to me the obvious solution seems to be calling it from a CRON-style Scheduled Task.

According to my internet searches this seems to be possible but as I'm quite new to WSO2 ESB haven't found a way to get this done yet.

Is this really possible?
If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to write your own task / class / javascript / mediatior

You should have a look at https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Writing+Tasks+Sample
: This custom task sample cover something similar to your needs

An other sample based on a javascript that look if a file exist :

```
    <script language="js">
    importPackage(Packages.org.apache.commons.vfs2);
    if(VFS.getManager().resolveFile("smb://DOMAIN\\user:password@hostname/dir/myfile.xml").exists()){
      mc.setProperty("THIS_FILE_EXIST","true")
    } else {
      mc.setProperty("THIS_FILE_EXIST","false")          
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I hoped to sort this out using the ESB's built-in modules, with no customizations, anyway it looks like this is not possible... So I'll start from the link above, it seems reasonable enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VFS transport does not support cron expressions..You can define polling interval in seconds

Comment: Yes, I know. In fact I was asking whether it's possible to create a Scheduled Task and invoke the VFS Transport from there...

Comment: Transports for proxies.If you define scheduled task to call a VFS proxy, VFS proxy needs the polling interval, it is a must parameter. Both together, i do not think it will work..